# how to make a variable a unique key in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

For example if I have this schema

```js
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    _todo: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo'}]
});
```

I would like the username to be a unique key that cannot be duplicated by other users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add a constraint with the `unique` attribute. This will also add a "unique" index for the field to your collection:

```js
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: { type: String, unique: true },
    email: String,
    password: String,
    _todo: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Todo'}]
});
```

Comment: The correct answer is below, especially given "you should create your indexes using the MongoDB shell rather than relying on mongoose to do it for you."

Answer (score 17):

I came across the same issue. But can't be solved by the accepted answer.

For my example is very simple, just make the `name` unique.

```
var FoolSchema = Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      index: true,
      required: true
    }
})
```

I can save the duplicate name every time.

Then I find this link:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html#unique-doesnt-work

The solution is `createIndex` from `mongoDB`, not from mongoose.

1. start mongo shell
   `mongo`, and `use yourdbName`
2. run `db.foos.getIndexes()` (you can't see the `"unique" : true,` )
3. `db.foos.createIndex( { "name": 1 }, { unique: true } )`
4. try step 2. The results should contains `unique`.

Hope it could help someone.

**EDIT**
If your `foo` table collections contain the duplicated names, you might get error on step 3:

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: mategoal-dev.categories index: name_1 dup key: { : \"TheName\" }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "codeName" : "DuplicateKey"
}
```

Then remove all the data or duplicated one(haven't test) first:

```
db.foos.remove({})
```

Then try step 3 again.

Comment: [Restart mongo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535610/mongoose-unique-index-not-working) makes it work without using the mongo shell solution. At least it works for me.