# Mongoose.js find() inside a find()

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to do a find inside a find on Node with Mongoose?

I'm letting a user change their email address, but I have to make sure the email hasn't been used by any other user before I save the new email.

I want to do this:

```
/*************************************************************
* MY_USER - PROFILE UPDATE
*************************************************************/
app.put('/api/myuser/info', auth, function(req, res) {
  serverLog.log(req, production, {});

  // User ID
  var myUserID = req.session.passport.user._id;

  if ( myUserID && validateID(myUserID) ) {

     User.findOne({
        _id: myUserID
     }, function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (data == null) {
           res.sendStatus(401);
           console.log(401);
        }
        // Data
        else {

           // Update Email
           if (req.body.email) {

              // Check valid email
              if ( validateEmail(req.body.email) ) {
                 console.log('validateEmail');

                 // Check Unique Email
                 User.findOne({
                    'local.user.info.email': email
                 }, function(err, user) {

                    if(err) return err;

                    if ( user ) {
                       // Email already in use
                       res.status(400).send('ERROR: Email Already in Use');
                       return;
                    }
                    console.log('uniqueEmail ' + true);
                    // Update email
                    user.local.user.info.email = req.body.email;
                 })

              }
              // Bad Email
              else {
                 res.status(400).send('ERROR: Not a propper Email');
                 return;
              }

           }

           // SAVE USER DATA               
           if ( info_sent ) {

              user.save(function(err, data) {
                 if (err) throw err;

                 res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                 res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data.local.user.info, null, 3));
                 return;
              });
           }
           // NO INFO WAS SENT
           else {
              res.status(400).send('ERROR: No information was sent.');
              return;
           }
        }
     });
  } 
  // Bad / No User ID
  else {
     res.sendStatus(401);
  }
});
```

I find the user, then check if email is in use
How would one go about doing this?

Comment: So how it goes? Did your code work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose & unique field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971666/mongoose-unique-field)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21971666/mongoose-unique-field

Comment: Also would take a look at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator

Comment: That code ^ does not work. Can't do a find inside a find asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because you do not save your user in the callback function that checks if email already exists. Also consider using *Promise* to avoid callback hell

Anyway, you can do it like this:

```
// Check Unique Email
User.findOne({'local.user.info.email': email }, (err, user) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  if (user) {
    return res.status(400).send('ERROR: Email Already in Use');
  } else {  // SAVE USER DATA        
   if (info_sent) {
     user.save((err, data) => {
       if (err) throw err;
       res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(data.local.user.info, null, 3));
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(400).send('ERROR: No information was sent.');
    }
 }
```