# How can i add a function which checks if email is repeated or not and then registers the person?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I'm using Node.js, express.js, mongoose, and pug.
I'm trying to create a registration/signup/login system. The name and email are being stored to mongoose database with schema specified for the name, email and date. The name and email value come from the pug page which sends a post request. I will add other registration details later on in the code, but I'm unable to think about a way to implement email checking.

This is my /routes/index.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const {
  check,
  validationResult
} = require('express-validator');
const router = express.Router();
//Mongoose

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


var registration = require('../models/registrations') //Important

//Routes

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------REGISTER/SIGN UP
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('./home.pug')
})

router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
  res.render('register', {
    title: 'Register'
  });
});

router.post('/register', [
  check('name')
  .isLength({
    min: 5
  })
  .withMessage('Please enter a name'),
  check('email')
  .isLength({
    min: 14
  })
  .withMessage('Please enter an email'),
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);



  if (errors.isEmpty()) {

    const regis = new registration(req.body);
    regis.save()
      .then(() => {
        res.send('Thank you for your registration!');
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        res.send('Sorry! Something went wrong.');
      })
  } else {
    res.status(422).render('register', {
      title: 'Registration form',
      errors: errors.array(),
      data: req.body,
    });
  }
  console.log(req.body)
})
//Register-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------LOGIN
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'Login'
  });
});

//Login-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x-x




router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.render('about', {
    title: 'About'
  });
});




module.exports = router;
```

I have tried using this:

```js
var emailcheck = registration.findOne({email: req.body.email});

if (emailcheck){
  //Give error
  }else{
  //Run this
  }
```

However, it didn't work like I thought it would. Sometimes it gave me an error, sometimes it would run even when the email is already used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if that data already exist in the database during update (Mongoose And Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882938/how-to-check-if-that-data-already-exist-in-the-database-during-update-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `registration.findOne` function returns `Promise` and you don't handle it properly. Try `await` it

```js
var emailcheck = await registration.findOne({email: req.body.email});
```

Or do it in closures manner

```js
registration.findOne({email: req.body.email}).then(emailcheck => {
  if (emailcheck){
   //Give error
  }else{
   //Run this
  }
})
```

Comment: Await gives me a syntax error: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.

Comment: I also checked the manner of the closure, it runs fine but fails when I test it.

Comment: I have tried it again. I believe I had some issue. It is now fixed. Thanks for the help!